# Avatar display visual studio changes query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been programming a forum for funsies that I'll eventually be creating into a sharepoint add-in. I'm currently unable to solve an issue with the _Layout.cshtml page as in Visual Studio 2010 the page is laid out differently than it is in 2013. No problem right, I still get my page aware that there is an avatar on the nav bar however in 2013 it refuses to show then picture. Code and screenshot links provided below.

Visual Studio 2013(broken):
[image: Visual Studio 2013 result]

**_Layout.cshtml 2013**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Forum</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"> <img src="#" /></p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Forums", "Index", "Forum")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Avatar", "SelectAvatar", "Avatar")</li>
                        @Html.Action("Avatar", "Layout")

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - ID</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**LayoutController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LbForum.Models;

namespace LbForum.Controllers
{
    public class LayoutController : Controller
    {

        private IStateRepository stateRepository = null;

        public LayoutController()
            : this(new SessionStateRepository())
        {

        }

        public LayoutController(IStateRepository sessionStateRepository)
        {
            this.stateRepository = sessionStateRepository;
        }

        //
        // GET: /Layout/

        public ContentResult Avatar()
        {
            string imgPath = "~/Images/Avatars";

            ForumUserState forumUserState = stateRepository.GetForumUserState();

            if (forumUserState.AvatarFileName != string.Empty)
            {
                imgPath += forumUserState.AvatarFileName;
            }
            else
            {
                imgPath += "avatar1.jpg";
            }
            string imgTag = string.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='User Avatar' width='40' height='40'/>", imgPath);

            return new ContentResult() { Content = imgTag };
        }


    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2010(fixed):
[image: Visual Studio 2010 result]

**_Layout.cshtml 2010**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Forum</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"><</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

               @Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home",
                                           new { area = "" },
                                           new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                  .ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]",
                                          "<img src=\"/images/forum.jpg\" alt=\"QA Forum logo\" />"))


            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Forums", "Index", "Forum")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Threads", "Index", "Thread")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Posts", "Index", "Post")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Avatar", "SelectAvatar", "Avatar")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin")</li>
                    @Html.Action("Avatar", "Layout")

                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - ID</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't an apples-to-apples comparison; You're using two different methods, neither of which tell us anything about the problem. Could you also provide the rendered output (as the client sees it)? Gut instinct tells me your Avatar action is rendering a bogus resource url while `/images/forum.jpg` works absolutely fine.

Comment: being logged in or not provides the same issue, i can provide my controller and model for the avatar if that's of any use

Comment: That wasn't my point. One method uses `@Html.Action` while the other is using `@Html.Raw`. Your original issue implied it was the VS version and nothing else had changes, but there are obvious code differences. And yes, the controller's action would help (but final output would be more relevant).

Comment: It may make sense to break this piece of functionality out into an HtmlHelper, btw (e.g. `@Html.Avatar()`)

Comment: Added controller code, this is my first time doing this project so if my ability to answer is terrible i apologise, trying to get to grips with it still

Comment: No worried, everyone had to learn sometime. However need to update at least one more time; I'm looking for the code that's called by `@Html.Action("Avatar", "Layout")`, so need the `LayoutController` so I can see how the avatar is being assembled. I also need the final output (visit the page in a browser and view-source, then provide the code related to the avatar itself (don't need the whole page)).

Comment: Added layout controller :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we have the meat'n'potatoes...

Your 2010 example (which is working) is simply referencing `/images/forum.jpg` (which appears to exist as an asset on your site). So all is fine there.

The 2012 version is appears you tried to refactor into a ChildAction. By doing so you've also switched how the resource is located, referencing `~/Images/avatars` instead of just `/Images/avatars` (note the tilde).

For the simplest "check if it works" path (and assuming your `/images/forum.jpg` file still exists) try just outputting a hard-coded value in your child action first:

```
    public ContentResult Avatar()
    {
        string imgPath = "/images/forums.jpg"; // Hard-coded
        string imgTag = string.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='User Avatar' width='40' height='40'/>", imgPath);

        return new ContentResult() { Content = imgTag };
    }
```

If that works, it has to do with the way you assemble the path. Remember locations to clients should be relative your website, so `~/` means nothing to them.

Some general guidance:

1. Decorate this action with `[ChildActionOnly]` to avoid being called directly.
2. Use a view and pass it the url as the model to avoid mixing logic/presentation.
3. Consider moving this code, altogether, into an HtmlHelper and avoid the round-trip to another controller.

Taking bullet points 1 & 2 and applying them:

**LayoutController.cs**:

```
public class LayoutController : Controller
{
  /* snip */

  // Hard-coded values should be const
  const String AvatarDefaultImage = "avatar1.jpg";

  [ChildActionOnly]
  public PartialViewResult Avatar()
  {
    var forumUserState = stateRepository.GetForumUserState();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(forumUserState.AvatarFileName))
    {
      // Pass off the URL as the model
      return PartialView(model: forumUserState.AvatarFileName);
    }
    // default fallback
    return PartialView(model: AvatarDefaultImage);
  }
}
```

**~/Views/Layout/Avatar.cshtml**:

```
@model String

<img src="/Images/Avatars/@Model" alt="User Avatar" width="40" height="40"/>
```

Comment: Awesome! I've added the suggestions and it makes sense but does [ChildAction] appear in MVC4 ? because when I'm getting missing assembly errors but I have the mvc references. I can however apply [ChildActionOnly] if that's  the same thing, appreciate the support ^^

Comment: Sorry, yes. ChildActionOnly is the correct attribute.